# What is the name of Python's "vars()" function in vb.net?

Tags: python, vb.net, function

I have this simple piece of code:

```
##Variables representing a table of 5 rows and 5 columns:

r1c1, r1c2, r1c3, r1c4, r1c5 = "","","","",""
r2c1, r2c2, r2c3... = "","","","",""
#for all 5 rows. (I know this is not the best way to do things, but bare with me)
for r in range(1,6):
    for c in range(1,6):
        currentPos= "r"+str(r)+"c"+str(c)
        vars()[currentPos]="identified"
        #print(currentPos)
print(r1c1)
print(r1c2)
print(r...)
```

All of these variables actually represent a number of objects in my vb.net program, whose .text property I want to alter to a value.

In essence, I don't know what the vb version of the python "var()" function is, if there is any at all.

Further detail: I actually want all the fields and rows from a database to correspond to each positioned textbox in my vb program.

Alternative solutions are also okay.

Comment: It's `vars()` function **not** `var()` function.. :)

Comment: That is ghastly code.  It's bad enough that Python lets you do that - VB.Net has more than enough nasty old cruft hanging around, you don't need to bring Python's dirty laundry in there too.  Just re-write this using sane data structures.

Comment: Rather than trying to translate code directly, think about what functionality you're trying to implement and then write the best VB code you can to implement it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the reason i am asking is because I can't do that. i literally cannot find any function, or anything, that can help me make my code perform this. I can do it in python, which is why I included it. I could have just asked about my vb problem specifically, but then I would have gotten a larger variety of ways to do this, when I want to know if there's any good way to do it in this specific style. I want to know how to do it, not be told to do it. That's literally why I am asking.

Comment: I suggest that you learn how VB.NET works. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: no, but for loops are a very real thing in them. that's enough to know that you CAN make the program run through the text propety of every object and modify it.